# Enabling XSTLProcessor in XAMPP 1.7.4

Tags: php, xslt, xampp

Getting an error *Class 'XSLTProcessor' not found in...*

How do I install this class, working with XAMPP 1.7.4, upgrading is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Added extension=php_xsl.dll to php.ini.

Thought that it did not have this option since the line does not exist in XAMPP 1.7.4